# "Secure connection failed" SSL error on PHP script depending on the GET parameters?

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, https

I'm using Wordpress with forced HTTPS (at the wp-config.php level) and am having a strange problem with the `https://mysite.example/wp-admin/admin.php` url.

When viewing the theme's headers editor section at *"https://mysite.example/wp-admin/admin.php?page=Headers"*, the SSL is successful. However, when another variable is added, i.e *"https://mysite.example/wp-admin/admin.php?page=Headers&item_name=Site+Header&item_id=default_topbar__languages"*, the SSL connection fails on chrome and Firefox on multiple devices. `Secure Connection Failed: The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.`

My first instinct would be that this shouldn't happen because the URL goes to the same file - which shouldn't have a chance to execute (changing the outcome) before the SSL connection is established.

The status bar loops between "Waiting for server", "Performing TLS handshake" and "looking up site".

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this kind of behavior on one specific page - only when the GET parameters are added? I've already tried checking the SSL certificate is valid (it is), and the .htaccess for any strange loops (there aren't).

Is my assumption that the parameters shouldn't affect anything because the script can't execute before SSL is established mistaken?

Thanks!

**edit**
This client is on shared hosting (Godaddy) so I can't see any vhosts or config files. However the .htaccess file is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my\-site\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.my\-site\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^testing$ "http\:\/\/my\-site\.com\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my\-site\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.my\-site\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^us$ "http\:\/\/my\-site\.com\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my\-site\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.my\-site\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^us\/ja\/$ "https\:\/\/my\-site\.com\/ja\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The query string shouldn't affect this by default. However, since we have no idea what your vhost settings/htaccess looks like or if there is anything in your code that does something specific if those parameters are present, we can't even begin to guess.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for your reply. I attached my htaccess file, I don't see anything obvious that would cause this. We don't have access to the apache/vhosts/ssl config because this site is on a shared godaddy server which has proprietary tools you have to use to manage that. The certificate is checking out OK on all the SSL checker sites I've looked at though.